# Creating a progress bar using php

Tags: php, css, progress-bar

I am attempting to create a progress bar using PHP to display how much money remains of a users' amount. I currently have the following code:

appQueries.php

```
<?php

class appQueries {
    protected $db = null;
    public function __construct($db){
      $this->db = $db;
}

public function costsSum($user_id){
    $query = "SELECT SUM(value) FROM costs 
    $pdo = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $pdo->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
    $pdo->execute();
    return $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function getMaxAmount(){
    $query = "SELECT maxAmount FROM users;
    $pdo = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $pdo->execute();
    return $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

}

Comment: If you use `%` on `#amountcompleted`. You want to go up from `html,body` with `height:100%`. Or have a `parent` with a set `height` in `px` or other than `%`.

Comment: Apologies, I don't quite understand what you mean..

Comment: I cannot see your `HTML`. But in order to make `%` run. You want to have a `parent element` which has a size defined. In `px`. Get me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch out these lines of code with these:

You have to set a height for the divs and then you have to decide on what colors you want the divs to be.  Also, and this is my preference.  When echoing out html, I usually use single quotes on the outsides of the echo and I use double quotes for the html attributes.

This should work though.

```
echo '<div id="progressbar" style="height:50px;background-color:yellow;">';
echo '<div id="amountcompleted" style="height:50px; width:'  . $progressBarWidth . '% !important; background-color:lightblue"></div>';
echo '</div>';
```

I didn't see that you had your CSS posted.  Here is CSS solution..  You did not declare your CSS classes in your attributes.

```
echo '<div id="progressbar" class="progressbar">';
echo '<div id="amountcompleted" class="amountcompleted" style="width:'  . $progressBarWidth . '% !important;"></div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: @unistudent1995 I have updated my answer again.  I did not see you had your CSS posted.